# Command Completion does not work on names containing `:`

Tags: bash, files, permissions, autocomplete

I have been hacking a Linux system (in an attempt to get BlueTooth working, although this is not relevant).

There are directories structured as below

```
   /var/lib/bluetooth/
    ├── B8:27:EB:8E:A8:4D
    │   ├── 00:12:A1:12:09:51
    │   │   └── info
    │   ├── 34:88:5D:70:53:44
    │   │   └── info
    │   ├── cache
    │   │   ├── 00:12:A1:12:09:51
    │   │   ├── 34:88:5D:70:53:44
    │   │   ├── E4:CE:8F:03:00:6D
    │   │   └── F8:77:B8:AD:BC:AC
    │   └── settings
```

I have been trying to manipulate these, but Command Completion does not work on any of the names containing `:`. Is this normal, and is there any way I can get Command Completion to work. Typing these cryptic names in full is tedious, and error prone.

`sudo ls /var/lib/bluetooth/B8:27:EB:8E:A8:4D/34:88` shows no completion
`sudo ls /var/lib/bluetooth/B8:27:EB:8E:A8:4D/34:88:5D:70:53:44` is OK

Using wildcards e.g. `00*` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: 1) Which shell? 2) The  wildcard thing is deeply strange and if you could [edit] in a transcript of the failure it would be informative.

Comment: @MichaelHomer `bash` There is no error, just nothing happens. wildcards show `No such file or directory`

Comment: Show what you're typing before hitting tab

Comment: Show a transcript of the whole thing, including what you typed and what errors you get. Include `ls`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `sudo ls`

If you are having to use `sudo` in order to gain access to the directory in order to list it, what makes you think that your shell can list it?

This isn't a problem with command-line completion, wildcards, colons, quotation marks, or the version of your shell.  It's a very simple permissions problem.

Your do not have the access rights to list that directory.  Thus your shell, running as your account, cannot.  Since it cannot list the directory, it cannot complete names within it or expand wildcards.